# How to unpack multiple keys in a Spark DataSet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have the following `DataSet`, with the following structure.

```
case class Person(age: Int, gender: String, salary: Double)
```

I want to determine the **average** salary by `gender` and `age`, thus I group the `DS` by both keys. I've encountered two main problems, one is that both keys are mixed in a single one, but I want to keep them in two different columns, the other is that the `aggregated` column gets a silly long name and I can't figure out how to rename it (apparently `as` and `alias` won't work) all of this using the `DS API`.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(List(Person(100000.00, "male", 27), 
  Person(120000.00, "male", 27), 
  Person(95000, "male", 26),
  Person(89000, "female", 31),
  Person(250000, "female", 51),
  Person(120000, "female", 51)
)).toDF.as[Person]

df.groupByKey(p => (p.gender, p.age)).agg(typed.avg(_.salary)).show()

+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        key| TypedAverage(line2503618a50834b67a4b132d1b8d2310b12.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$Person)|          
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
|[female,31]|  89000.0... 
|[female,51]| 185000.0...
|  [male,27]| 110000.0...
|  [male,26]|  95000.0...
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aliasing is an untyped action, so you must retype it after. And the only way to unpack the key is to do it after, via a select or something:

```
df.groupByKey(p => (p.gender, p.age))
  .agg(typed.avg[Person](_.salary).as("average_salary").as[Double])
  .select($"key._1",$"key._2",$"average_salary").show
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to achieve both goals is to `map()` from the aggregation result to the `Person` instance again:

```scala
.map{case ((gender, age), salary) => Person(gender, age, salary)}
```

The result will look best if slightly re-arrange the order of arguments in the case class'es constructor:

```scala
case class Person(gender: String, age: Int, salary: Double)
```

```sql
+------+---+--------+
|gender|age|  salary|
+------+---+--------+
|female| 31| 89000.0|
|female| 51|185000.0|
|  male| 27|110000.0|
|  male| 26| 95000.0|
+------+---+--------+
```

Full code:

```scala
import session.implicits._
val df = session.sparkContext.parallelize(List(
  Person("male", 27, 100000),
  Person("male", 27, 120000),
  Person("male", 26, 95000),
  Person("female", 31, 89000),
  Person("female", 51, 250000),
  Person("female", 51, 120000)
)).toDS

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.scalalang.typed
df.groupByKey(p => (p.gender, p.age))
  .agg(typed.avg(_.salary))
  .map{case ((gender, age), salary) => Person(gender, age, salary)}
  .show()
```